# Oracle 12c - view plans access unnecessary tables

Tags: oracle, view, oracle12c

I am hoping for an explanation of some view + optimizer behavior

lets make a view like this

```
select e.employee_name, e.employee_active, ei.marital_status
    from employees e
    left join employee_info ei on ei.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

Then lets access it like this

```
select distinct employee_name from employee_view where employee_id = 13
```

In my head, I'm thinking we do not need to access employee_info table at all for this query to execute in a functionally correct way. Yet, when I explain plans on this query, I see it accessing employee_info. Am I missing something that makes it necessary to actually perform that join? If it is functionally equivalent to not hit that table, is there a way to stop that from happening in 12c?

Comment: A View by definition is nothing but a parsed SQL stored   in the DB, when you query the View it actually executed the query and then returns the data. If you want to select only  employee_name from employees  table then why dont you create a view which only select from employees table and then the view will access the employees table.

Comment: Please provide *table definition* including `PK`and `FK` and the view definition. Your *example* of view query does not contain `employee_id` which leads to `ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEE_ID": invalid identifier`

Answer (score 1):

You *deduction* is basically correct, but you must take in account than not every *optimization* that is *possible* is also *implemented*.

Oracle pragmatically observes the *potential* and decides where the optimization should be extended.

For example there were times where the predicate `where 1=1 and ...` could confuse the optimizer, but as this "construction" is used rather often, in recent version the optimizer recognised it and ignore it without side effects.

Your setup of *outer* join to child, while selecting `distinct` from the parent columns only is probably not very frequent and therefore not yet covered.

Here a similar example, where Oracle can skip a table from a view (Note the `PK` and `FK` definition, which is *crutial*)

```
create table employees (
employee_id  int primary key,
employee_name varchar2(10),
employee_active varchar2(10));

create table employee_info (
employee_id int,
marital_status varchar2(10));

alter table employee_info
add constraint emp_info_fk1 foreign key (employee_id)
references employees (employee_id);

create or replace view employee_view as
select e.EMPLOYEE_ID, e.employee_name, e.employee_active, ei.marital_status
    from employees e
    join employee_info ei on ei.employee_id = e.employee_id;
```

The query `select   marital_status from employee_view where employee_id = 13` can skip the `employees` (parent) table and access only the child table

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |               |     1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMPLOYEE_INFO |     1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
    1 - filter("EI"."EMPLOYEE_ID"=13)
```

More information and links in [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8154375/4808122)